# Ghidra export to C header, how to remove ".conflict"?

Tags: ghidra

When using the export to C header functionality of Ghidra it keeps outputting double and triple symbols with ".conflict" appended. When I change how the data type manager should deal with conflicts it still keeps outputting them. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

It prevents Ghidra from parsing that same output back into another version of the application.

**edit: adding clarification as requested**
I'm playing around with ioncube and what I'm trying to do is:

- Compile PHP with debug enabled
- Extract type information
- Use type information on the ioncube executable

What I mean with 'use type information' is that I want to have structures available so that I can apply them manually. However when right clicking on the type manager and exporting the 'php with debug enables' to a C header, GHIDRA is not able to import the header file.

All the issues during import seem to be in regards to anonymous structures that besides the name also receive a '.conflict' append. I've temporarily resolved this by cleaning them up manually and just create the bare minimum to import. However it would be nice to do this as intended by GHIDRA.

Hope this clarifies a bit more.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you did and post your binary if possible

Comment: Hope the clarification makes the situation a bit more clear.